# How to add a custom context menu item to work item context menu in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

Hi i am new to azure devops and I want to add a custom context menu (...) item "view Latest Test Result" against each workitem type (Test Case) so that user can directly navigate to Test Run Details page.

I don't see any vsts extension for cusotm context menu item. Is anyone guide me how we can achieve this functionality? Please check the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVCWn.jpg for details.

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not exactly what you want (context menu), it does show the latest Test Results on a tab in the Test Case Work Item. Would the [View Latest Test Result](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=keesverhaar.viewlatesttestresult) extension work for you? If not, you can contribute to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/KeesV/kv-vsts-ViewLatestTestResult) of the extension or ask the author for this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I have checked the View Latest Test Result extension its for work item details page. I need the extension for context menu. First i want to just add item to context-menu and then sub-menu like when i hover to context-menu item "View Latest Test Result" it show me a sub-menu (extended menu) that show possible configurations for that test case then i select a specific configuration the it redirect me to specific test result detail page. Could you please guide me how i can achieve this?

Comment: The behaviour you are asking for is not possible (out of the box) in Azure DevOps or using the extension I mentioned without extensive modification. I would strongly suggest creating an issue on the GitHub repo I mentioned as your best possibility.